# How do I omit a key pair from an object based on its value?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using lodash.js and am trying to remove a key pair from the below object based on the *value* not the key name - note, I cannot use the key name:

```
var filters = {
   "filter1": "height",
   "filter2": "length",
   "filter3": "width"
}
```

This will remove a key pair by name

```
_.omit(filters, 'filter1');
```

Does anyone know how to removed it based upon value? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.omit`](http://lodash.com/docs#omit) with a callback:

```
_.omit(filters, function (value) {
    return value === 'width';
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`omit`](http://lodash.com/docs#omit) method accepts a callback, so you could just use this:

```
_.omit(filters, function(v){return v == "height";});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Hq4/)

Answer (score 2):

[According to the docs](http://lodash.com/docs#omit) `omit` it can take a call back argument that is a function that returns true for each pair that should be omitted. In that function you can do whatever crazy logic you like.

```
_.omit(filters, function(value, key, object) {
  return value === 'width'; // omit width
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer updated (2023) : v4.17.15

**API : omitBy(object, predicate)**

> [predicate=_.identity] (Function): The function invoked per property.

use [`omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy) that accepts a function callback on each value to be processed.

```js
_.omitBy(filters, function (value) {
    return value === 'width';
})
```